# Leaflet with Asp.Net markers won't drag

Tags: asp.net, leaflet, mapbox

I have an ASP.Net webform site.  I have created a map, with markers, but the markers will not drag.  I am not sure what the issue is, as the code is from other sites that work.  I am not sure if it is an asp.net issue.  I am using Leaflet and MapBox, for my maps.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
    #mapid {
        height: 600px;
    }

</style>
<div id="mapid"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindMapEvents();    
    })

function BindMapEvents() {

     L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox.streets',
        accessToken: 'pk.myKey'
    }).addTo(mymap);   
    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
    marker.dragging.enable();
}
function onMapClick(e) {
    marker = new L.marker(e.latlng, { draggable: 'true' });

      marker.on('dragend', function(event){
        var marker = event.target;
        var position = marker.getLatLng();
        marker.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng),{draggable:'true'});
        map.panTo(new L.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng))
      });
      mymap.addLayer(marker);
    };
</script>
```

The map and marker loads, but when I try to grab and move the marker, all it does is grab the map and move that.  Any suggestions on what can be causing this?

Comment: The code is not complete and has errors (missing `L.map()` instantiation, `map` vs `mymap`, undefined variables for some of the scopes). Fixing those makes the whole thing just work, e.g. https://plnkr.co/edit/qLXlaUi8VFpFSPWuScKG?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.  If you post this as a response, I can mark it up.